# Allowing only local access to a Wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress, geolocation

Hi I am researching the best method to accomplish the following: I have a Wordpress website and I want to only allow Canadians in the province of Manitoba to access it. So basically only local access. I have looked at several Wordpress Geolocation plugins. Would a Wordpress hook, that searched some online Geolocation Database service be better ?

The other part is what would be the best way to block access once I found out that the user was not from the province ?  Use a redirect to a page that states you cannot access this website ?

Comment: What were you planning to use to identify their location?

Answer (score 0):

So there is a few way of doing it.

The easy way, I think the plug-in wordfence provide ip filtering by geolocation. (see https://www.wordfence.com/help/blocking/#country-blocking )

Another way would be to apply rules directly in the firewall of your server.

and there must be other plug-ins or applications allowing to do the same....

Nevertheless, I would not do that, restricting user by location is quite dangerous, IP localisation is not always accurate. (for instance someone with a SIM-card from US, coming to your province, will have an ip of US on his phone). People using VPN can have access while being abroad  or being blocked while being here.
So it's depends on your goal and usage.

Comment: "(for instance someone with a SIM-card from US, coming to your province, will have an ip of US on his phone)" is not accurate. IP addresses get assigned by cell tower. But you're right in what you're saying. IP is not a good way to identify location in the slightest. Not to bad for a country block but terrible at state county levels

Comment: Not sure how I would define the ip range in Wordfence that would allow only access for Manitoba.

Comment: You could block all except Canada, that would be already a good start. A province scale blocking seems unrealistic for me based on ip address.

Comment: @user2197774 If my answer was helpful I would be glad if you vote it upand/or mark it as the answer to your question.